# how to parse xml output of mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I know there are several xml parsers for python, but I dont know which one would be good to parse outputs of mysql xml, I havent been successfully yet. The output looks like:

```
<resultset statement="select * from table where id > 5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="name">first</field>
    <field name="login">2021-08-16 13:44:35</field>
  </row>

  <row>
    <field name="name">second</field>
    <field name="login">2021-08-18 13:44:35</field>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

because the structure is quite simple here, I come about to write my own parser, but I would guess there should be already something to cover this case?!

Output should be a list of dicts with columns as keys and the value as the content of the row/column

Comment: Take a look at ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @balderman a list with dicts like `[{name:first,login:2021-08-16},{...}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<resultset statement="select * from table where id > 5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="name">first</field>
    <field name="login">2021-08-16 13:44:35</field>
  </row>

  <row>
    <field name="name">second</field>
    <field name="login">2021-08-18 13:44:35</field>
  </row>
</resultset>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for row in root.findall('.//row'):
    fields = []
    for field in row.findall('field'):
        fields.append((field.attrib['name'], field.text))
    data.append(fields)
print(data)
```

output

```
[[('name', 'first'), ('login', '2021-08-16 13:44:35')], [('name', 'second'), ('login', '2021-08-18 13:44:35')]]
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the loop with ```record = dict()
        for field in row.findall('field'):
            record[field.attrib['name']] = field.text
        data.append(record)``` to get a better output strucutre